# Deserializing JSON from TD Ameritrade

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am pulling in quote data from TD Ameritrade's API, and it's generating the following JSON:

```
{
  "AAPL": {
    "52WkHigh": 145.09,
    "52WkLow": 53.1525,
    "askId": "P",
    "askPrice": 121.08,
    "askSize": 1700,
    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
    "assetType": "EQUITY",
    "bidId": "P",
    "bidPrice": 121.06,
    "bidSize": 600,
    "bidTick": " ",
    "closePrice": 121.03,
    "cusip": "037833100",
    "delayed": "false",
    "description": "Apple Inc. - Common Stock",
    "digits": 4,
    "divAmount": 0.82,
    "divDate": "2021-02-05 00:00:00.000",
    "divYield": 0.68,
    "exchange": "q",
    "exchangeName": "NASD",
    "highPrice": 121.17,
    "lastId": "D",
    "lastPrice": 121.08,
    "lastSize": 200,
    "lowPrice": 119.16,
    "marginable": "true",
    "mark": 121.03,
    "markChangeInDouble": 0.0,
    "markPercentChangeInDouble": 0.0,
    "nAV": 0.0,
    "netChange": 0.05,
    "netPercentChangeInDouble": 0.0413,
    "openPrice": 120.4,
    "peRatio": 32.9702,
    "quoteTimeInLong": 1615597198023,
    "regularMarketLastPrice": 121.03,
    "regularMarketLastSize": 7,
    "regularMarketNetChange": 0.0,
    "regularMarketPercentChangeInDouble": 0.0,
    "regularMarketTradeTimeInLong": 1615582801729,
    "securityStatus": "Normal",
    "shortable": "true",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "totalVolume": 88105050,
    "tradeTimeInLong": 1615597198932,
    "volatility": 0.0085
  }
}
```

Class created from JSON:

```
public class Quote
{
    public float _52WkHigh { get; set; }
    public float _52WkLow { get; set; }
    public string askId { get; set; }
    public float askPrice { get; set; }
    public int askSize { get; set; }
    public string assetMainType { get; set; }
    public string assetType { get; set; }
    public string bidId { get; set; }
    public float bidPrice { get; set; }
    public int bidSize { get; set; }
    public string bidTick { get; set; }
    public float closePrice { get; set; }
    public string cusip { get; set; }
    public string delayed { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int digits { get; set; }
    public float divAmount { get; set; }
    public string divDate { get; set; }
    public float divYield { get; set; }
    public string exchange { get; set; }
    public string exchangeName { get; set; }
    public float highPrice { get; set; }
    public string lastId { get; set; }
    public float lastPrice { get; set; }
    public int lastSize { get; set; }
    public float lowPrice { get; set; }
    public string marginable { get; set; }
    public float mark { get; set; }
    public float markChangeInDouble { get; set; }
    public float markPercentChangeInDouble { get; set; }
    public float nAV { get; set; }
    public float netChange { get; set; }
    public float netPercentChangeInDouble { get; set; }
    public float openPrice { get; set; }
    public float peRatio { get; set; }
    public long quoteTimeInLong { get; set; }
    public float regularMarketLastPrice { get; set; }
    public int regularMarketLastSize { get; set; }
    public float regularMarketNetChange { get; set; }
    public float regularMarketPercentChangeInDouble { get; set; }
    public long regularMarketTradeTimeInLong { get; set; }
    public string securityStatus { get; set; }
    public string shortable { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public int totalVolume { get; set; }
    public long tradeTimeInLong { get; set; }
    public float volatility { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling a Python Script to get the JSON data, which then redirects to my C# app.
However, when I deserialize it, no data is populating:

```
    public void GetQuotes(string symbol)
    {
        var errors = "";
        var results = "";
        this.psi.Arguments = $"\"{this.script}\" -q {symbol}";
        Quote quote;

        using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.Print(results);
            
            quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quote>(results);
            
        }

        MessageBox.Show(quote.symbol);
    }
```

I have been able to deserialize Json with relatively consistent success, but I can't figure out why I'm loading in blank objects from this JSON.

Comment: I believe you are missing the root object that this Quote is supposed to be part of.

Comment: Quote` is in the property `AAPL` of the root object. You need another class with that as a property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a root object that contains your Quote object.

```
public class RootObject 
{
  public Quote AAPL { get;set;}
}
```

and deserialize to this,

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(results);
Quote quote = rootObject.AAPL;
```

When you deserialize to Quote, you are getting nulls because there is no property in the original json that matches with any of the Quote properties. Since your JSON contains 1 property (AAPL) and its value is of type `Quote`, you have to deserialize to RootObject.

Based on your point on variable key, you should deserialize to `Dictionary<string, Quote>`.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Quote>>(results);
Quote quote = obj.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

You can also list all keys and use foreach loop but if you know there will always be only one key, `FirstOrDefault()` will work as well.

Comment: "AAPL" will change constantly. Does that matter?

Comment: Then instead of creating a rootobject, deserialize to `Dictionary<string, Quote>`

Comment: @jDave1984 you might want to accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: I have, albeit serializing to a `Dictionary<string, Quote>` is what I went with, because TD will return an entire array of those objects

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jawad for the quick hint. Because 'AAPL' is an ever-changing key, I had to deserialize the JSON into a `Dictionary<string, Quote>` to get the data populating:

```
    public void GetQuotes(string symbol)
    {
        var errors = "";
        var results = "";
        this.psi.Arguments = $"\"{this.script}\" -q {symbol}";
        Dictionary<string, Quote> quotes;

        using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.Print(results);

            
            quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Quote>>(results);
        }
    }
```